# How to parse file names (images) and assign them to a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I am relatively new in Django and building an e-commerce application. I have a folder with images (they are in the static directory), and lots of products (~15000, I pull the product data from an API.). Unfortunately I do not pull the image data from the API, instead I have a folder with all the images, and their name contains a fragment of the product.name string.

```
e.g
product.name = AH 285/55 R16 Turanza AH325
image_path = static/products/images/Turanza__1.png
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following pseudo code:

```
if product.name (the string) is contained in the image_name(path of the image), save the image and associate it with the model, otherwise pass.
```

- 

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=15, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    image1 = ...
    image2 = ...
```

or

```
class Image(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, ...)
    name = models.CharField(...)
```

How would I approach this? Maybe a model property? What is the best practice for a problem like this? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to me is to pass an extra parameter to the Product model instance when creating it, on this case the filename. Something like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=15, null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    image1 = ...
    image2 = ...

   @classmethod
   def create(cls, filename):
        product = cls(name=filename)
        return product
```

Then it would work like this:

```
product = Product.create("filename")
```

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/instances/#model-instance-methods).